# How can I create a group by on part of a string using LINQ?

Tags: c#

I have a list of ViewsHistory objects that's sorted by UtcNow:

```
var views = List<ViewHistory>
```

ViewHistory Class:

```
public class ViewHistory
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string YYMMDD { get; set; }
    public int UtcNow { get; set; }
    public int Learn { get; set; }
    public int Practice { get; set; }
    public int Quiz { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way using LINQ that I can create a new list summing up the totals for Learn, Practice and Quiz by YYMM?

Comment: That looks fairly date'ish, why are you storing it as a string? Also look up `String.Substring`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

```
var views = new List<ViewHistory>
{
    new ViewHistory {YYMMDD = "190515", Learn = 1, Practice = 2, Quiz = 3},
    new ViewHistory {YYMMDD = "190514", Learn = 5, Practice = 6, Quiz = 7},
    new ViewHistory {YYMMDD = "190415", Learn = 100, Practice = 110, Quiz = 120},
    new ViewHistory {YYMMDD = "190414", Learn = 150, Practice = 160, Quiz = 170}
};

var monthlyTotals = views.GroupBy(
    v => v.YYMMDD.Substring(0, 4),
    v => v,
    (yearMonth, groupedViews) =>
        new
        {
            YearMonth = yearMonth,
            LearnSum = groupedViews.Sum(view => view.Learn),
            PracticeSum = groupedViews.Sum(view => view.Practice),
            QuizSum = groupedViews.Sum(view => view.Quiz)
        }).ToList();
```

#### Results

**`monthlyTotals`** (copied from Visual Studio Locals window while debugging)

```
monthlyTotals   Count = 2   System.Collections.Generic.List<<>f__AnonymousType0<string, int, int, int>>
    [0] { YearMonth = "1905", LearnSum = 6, PracticeSum = 8, QuizSum = 10 } <Anonymous Type>
    [1] { YearMonth = "1904", LearnSum = 250, PracticeSum = 270, QuizSum = 290 } <Anonymous Type>
```

#### Rather not use anonymous types?

And, of course, if you prefer not to use an anonymous type, you could define a new class (let's say `MonthlyViewTotals` for example) and instantiate a list of those for your `monthlyTotals` instead like this:

```
var monthlyTotals = views.GroupBy(
    v => v.YYMMDD.Substring(0, 4),
    v => v,
    (yearMonth, groupedViews) =>
        new MonthlyViewTotals        // <-- no more anonymous types
        {
            YearMonth = yearMonth,
            LearnSum = groupedViews.Sum(view => view.Learn),
            PracticeSum = groupedViews.Sum(view => view.Practice),
            QuizSum = groupedViews.Sum(view => view.Quiz)
        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with `GroupBy` LINQ expression:

```
 var views = new List<ViewHistory>();
            views.Add(new ViewHistory {YYMMDD = "190530", Learn = 20, Practice = 1, Quiz = 30});
            views.Add(new ViewHistory { YYMMDD = "190531", Learn = 1, Practice = 1, Quiz = 30 });
            views.Add(new ViewHistory { YYMMDD = "190529", Learn = 2, Practice = 1, Quiz = 30 });
            views.Add(new ViewHistory { YYMMDD = "190410", Learn = 2, Practice = 1, Quiz = 30 });
            var newViews = views.GroupBy(t => t.YYMMDD.Substring(0, 4))
                .Select(t => new
                {
                    yymm = t.Key,
                    learnSum = t.Select(f => f.Learn).Sum(),
                    practiceSum = t.Select(f => f.Practice).Sum(),
                    quizSum = t.Select(f => f.Quiz).Sum()
                }).ToList();
```

**Result**

```
{ yymm = "1905", learnSum = 23, practiceSum = 3, quizSum = 90 },
{ yymm = "1904", learnSum = 2, practiceSum = 1, quizSum = 30 }
```

Comment: note the `YYMM` in OP, it may or may not be relevant or a typo